# spring-boot upgrade from 1.3.2 to 1.3.3: logback issue

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, logback, spring-data-neo4j-4

We've hit an issue when upgrading from spring-boot 1.3.2 to the recently released 1.3.3.

Our application has been making use of the following dependencies, each the latest, without issue:

```
    <neo4j.version>2.3.2</neo4j.version>
    <sdn.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</sdn.version>
    <sdn.rest.version>3.4.0.RELEASE</sdn.rest.version>
    <neo4j.ogm.version>1.1.5</neo4j.ogm.version>
```

Today I upgraded our spring-boot and Spring Data Neo4j -based application, which starts and works well with spring-boot 1.3.2.RELEASE, by changing the pom.xml from:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

With this being literally the only change, the application now fails to start with the following error:

...

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.EnsureExceptionHandling.process(Lch/qos/logback/core/pattern/Converter;)V
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.PatternLayoutBase.start(PatternLayoutBase.java:88)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder.start(PatternLayoutEncoder.java:28)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA.end(NestedComplexPropertyIA.java:167)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:77)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:152)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:143)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:122)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:378)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:328)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:349)
    at com.mycompany.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:35)
```

As expected, returning to 1.3.2.RELEASE does not cause any issues.

Searching so far reveals no trail to follow. Comparing the `mvn dependency:tree` output between using spring-boot 1.3.2.RELEASE and 1.3.3.RELEASE, I can see that the transient dependencies of ch.qos.logback:logback-classic and ch.qos.logback:logback-access jars have changed from 1.1.3 for spring-boot 1.3.2.RELEASE to 1.1.5 for spring-boot 1.3.3.RELEASE, while ch.qos.logback:logback-core remains at 1.1.3 for both spring-boot flavors.

Does anyone have any idea of what the underlying issue is (I'm guessing the class failing to instantiate has been removed or relocated) and/or -- more importantly -- what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: Please add the output of `mvn dependency:tree`. You probably have another dependency which is forcing it back to 1.1.3 instead of using spring boots 1.1.5.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Spring Boot is missing some dependency management for `logback-core` which is allowing different versions to creep in. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5304) to address that.

In the meantime, you can avoid the problem by adding your own dependency management for it to your pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, your suggestion of explicitly adding the logback-core dependency fixed the issue. In our case, I set it to make use of 1.1.5. and added a comment that this dependency should only be required while using spring-boot 1.3.3.

Comment: @Andy looks like there is a mistake with schema. <dependencies> element should be declared.

Comment: @ivanenok Thanks. Not sure why the reviewers rejected your edit. I've made it myself.