# springboot upgrade from 1.2.1 to 1.3.3 logback issue

Tags: spring, maven, logging, spring-boot, logback

I have upgraded  springboot version from 1.2.1 to 1.3.3  but i am facing some logback problems:

with version 1.2.1 it works perfectly fine:

**Exception**:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@14:16 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][layout][pattern]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedBasicPropertyIA - Unexpected aggregationType AS_BASIC_PROPERTY_COLLECTION
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@23:66 - no applicable action for [staticField], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][layout][staticField]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@24:24 - no applicable action for [key], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][layout][staticField][key]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@25:26 - no applicable action for [value], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][layout][staticField][value]]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:277)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.xx.yy.zz.hh.Application.main(Application.java:14)
```

**Logback.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

     <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>       
              <pattern>BlueBerry %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
    </appender> 


   <appender name="AMQP" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.logback.AmqpAppender">
              <!--  <filter class="com.xx.yy.util.LogsFilter" />-->
        <layout class="me.moocar.logbackgelf.GelfLayout">
      <pattern>BlueBerry %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        <shortMessageLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
               <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>  
                </shortMessageLayout>
                <useLoggerName>true</useLoggerName>
                <useThreadName>true</useThreadName>
                <useMarker>true</useMarker>
                <includeFullMDC>true</includeFullMDC>
                <fieldType>requestId:long</fieldType>
                <staticField class="me.moocar.logbackgelf.Field">
                  <key>_facility</key>
                  <value>GELF</value>
                </staticField>
     </layout>
        <host>srv173.xx.yy.com</host>
        <port>XXXX</port>
        <username>guest</username>
        <password>guest</password>
        <exchangeType>direct</exchangeType>
        <exchangeName>amq.direct</exchangeName>
        <applicationId>RabbitMq-IT-SE</applicationId>
     <routingKeyPattern>logs</routingKeyPattern>
        <generateId>true</generateId>
         <charset>UTF-8</charset> 
        <durable>true</durable>
         <abbreviation>36</abbreviation> 

        <deliveryMode>NON_PERSISTENT</deliveryMode>
        <declareExchange>true</declareExchange>

    </appender>   


    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <!--  <appender-ref ref="GELF TCP APPENDER"/>-->
        <appender-ref ref="AMQP"/>  
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I tried using Dependencies Management as mentioned in this question but it did not work for me:

[spring-boot upgrade from 1.3.2 to 1.3.3: logback issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738674/spring-boot-upgrade-from-1-3-2-to-1-3-3-logback-issue)

Comment: Could you please post the result of "mvn dependency:tree" ?

Answer (score 0):

Is upgrading to Spring Boot 1.3.4 an option ?

Although not exactly the same symptoms, it still points to logback dependency issues in 1.3.3. It seems to be fixed in 1.3.4: https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/153

```
Ugrading to Spring Boot 1.3.4 fixed this for me
```